# Create a program that returns the smallest cube which exceeds a non-negative integer n

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

So I'm trying to create a program which generates the smallest cube greater than an integer n.

```
def first_cube_above(n):
    #Return the smallest cube which exceeds the non-negative integer n.

    num = 1
    total = 0

    while total != 1:
        if pow(int(pow(n+num, 1/3)), 3) == n + num:
            total = 1
        else:
            num += 1

    print(n + num)
```

This seems to work for small integers but I can't figure out why is doesn't work for others. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As @martin.macko points out, you (wrongly) assume that `pow(pow(x, 1/3), 3) == x`. This does not hold due to floating point errors. In fact, running a quick check we find that there is (likely) only a small number of integers for which the above is true:

```
good = [x for x in range(10**7) if pow(pow(x, 1/3), 3) == x]
good_cubes = [x**3 for x in range(1000) if pow(pow(x**3, 1/3), 3) == x**3]
# len(good) = 50
```

On my machine, `good` numbers are

```
0, 1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 19, 23, 25, 27, 35, 44, 65, 66, 72, 73, 76, 83, 85, 91, 94, 96, 117, 127, 130, 139, 142, 147, 158, 170, 175, 513, 514, 520, 539, 547, 549, 551, 553, 562, 563, 576, 581, 601, 605, 663, 690, 699
```

and `good_cubes` are

```
0, 1, 8, 27
```

You can see that the largest perfect cube in the list is `27`, hence your error. You can try computing the next largest cube as follows:
`next_cube = ceil(x**(1/3))**3` where `ceil` is a function from `math` module.

Answer (score -1):

Your probem is with rounding errors with floats. Equality comparision `==` with floats is not exact. Better use precise arithemitcs.

The simplest solution would be to iterate up starting with 1 and stop on the first cube bigger then n:

```
a = 1
while a ** 3 <= n:
    a += 1
print(a ** 3)
```

However this solutions is quite ineficient as you need to iterate over O(n^(1/3)) numbers. But we know that for sure we don't need to iterate over very low numbers, so lets start with some number that for sure lower than the root but not much:

```
def cube(n):
    a = math.floor(pow(n, 1/3))
    while a ** 3 <= n:
        a += 1
    print(a ** 3)
```

The function works with huge numbers as well. For instance: `cube(9085409385209438540928540295843025325)` prints `9085409385221751364051702949589465608` which is a cube of `2086643068802`

Comment: Not on python 3.x. `/` is float division and `//` is integer division